# How do I create a device like /dev/zero, /dev/random to echo a specific value in demand?

Tags: filesystem, devices

I wish to have a customized device to echo a specific value like `/dev/zero` or `/dev/random`. But `/dev/zero` always outputs 0, `/dev/random` outputs a random number.

The specific value may be configured, for example --- 0x1234, 0x4321, 0xF6, or some ASCII streams `Yes` and `No`.

How do I create such a device?

Comment: And as for "/dev/random outputs a random number": No, it doesn't. It outputs random bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [How is /dev/zero created and how can I make variants like /dev/one?](https://superuser.com/a/481968/334516) (on SuperUser):

> There are device drivers that implement interaction with actual
>   devices, and there are device drivers that just react to read-write
>   requests in useful ways. If you want to you can sit down and write a
>   driver that returns the lyrics of the Star Spangeled Banner. But it's
>   a matter of coding ...

Unless you really need a device file, just use the [`yes`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/yes.1) command, which repeats its arguments *ad infinitum* (or `y`, if no argument is given):

```
$ yes Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
...
```

Also see:

- [How can I put a bit mask on /dev/zero so that I can get bytes other than zero?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208656/70524) (on Unix & Linux)
- [How do I get an equivalent of /dev/one in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10905062/2072269) (on Stack Overflow)